# Allocating memory to pointer of a derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, pointers

I have base class "Actor" and derived class "Outlaw"

"Outlaw" used to be its own base class and I could easily create a pointer using code:

```
Outlaw * outlaw = new Outlaw();
```

Now "Outlaw" inherits base type "Actor"

How would I write the new code to make a pointer to Outlaw class? I'm pretty new to C++ but have a good amount of C experience.

Comment: The `outlaw` in `Outlaw * outlaw` *is* a pointer to `Outlaw` already. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Best to immediately forget your C experience and learn C++ from scratch. They're really, really not that similar.

Answer (score 2):

It's exactly the same.

But first of all, maybe you don't need a dynamically allocated instance, maybe you just need a variable. In that case just a declare a variable, because due to speed of everything else in C++, dynamic allocation is costly (everything is relative, dynamic allocation is costly relative to an ordinary variable declaration). E.g.,

```
Outlaw outlaw;  // That's it!
```

If you do need dynamic allocation, best don't store the pointer raw.

Put it in a smart pointer immediately, e.g. a `std::shared_ptr` or a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Outlaw> outlaw( new Outlaw() );
```

To use the mentioned smart pointer classes, simply include `<memory>`.